# How can i hinder Eclipse from inserting CRLFs?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, newline, eclipse-juno

I just reinstalled Eclipse Juno.
The problem i have is when i create a new file and start writing, CRLFs are inserted on Return.

Second case: When i fully mark the text of a file (without CRLFs) ans `COPY` them into another file (i use `CRTL+A` and `DEL` to get rid of the file contents and then `PASTE` i get the file content with CRLFs!)

The resulting file looks like:

```
Test blah CRLF
Line two ... CRLF
CRLF
```

How can i get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this is to configure Eclipse accordingly.

Windows->Preferences->General->Workspace
In the right lower corner there is a setting called "New text fiel line delimiter" which i had to switch from Windows to Unix.

The already CRLF prensent i had to remove using Eclispe->File->Convert line delimiters to ->Unix .